# bash variable only retaining last line of grep

Tags: windows, bash

I'm trying to write a git hook which would allow me to collect unit testing reports post commit.

I'm on a windows machine but using bash for the hook itself. It seems to run fine. Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
test_summary=$(pytest -v | grep -E ".+\.py::.+[A-Z]+")
commit_id=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
```

The issue is that the variable `test_summary` retains only the last line from the `grep` match. I know my piped `pytest`/`grep` is fine since running it on an interactive msys terminal gives the correct output with all the matches:

```
$ pytest -v | grep -E ".+.py::.+[A-Z]+"
test_main.py::test_main PASSED                                           [ 33%]
test_main.py::test2 FAILED                                               [ 66%]
test_main.py::test3 PASSED                                               [100%]
```

`test_summary` contains the following:

```
$ echo $test_summary
 test_main.py::test3 PASSED [100%]3%]
```

Why does it only retain the last line plus some mumbo jumbo from the first line?

I don't get it....

Comment: `echo "$test_summary"`?

Comment: @Cyrus Yes? What about it?

Comment: I suggest to test it with shown quotes.

Comment: @Cyrus that does work... strange

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr**

OP is running these commands in a windows environment so (in this case) the variable is being loaded with `\r\n` line endings.

One idea for addressing this issue is to use [parameter substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html):

```
$ test_summary=$(pytest -v | grep -E ".+\.py::.+[A-Z]+")
$ test_summary="$(test_summary//$'\r'/}"                   # strip out '\r' characters

$ echo $test_summary
test_main.py::test_main PASSED                                           [ 33%]
test_main.py::test2 FAILED                                               [ 66%]
test_main.py::test3 PASSED                                               [100%]
```

Continue for details ...

---

We can simulate this behavior with the following:

```
$ cat pytest.out
test_main.py::test_main PASSED                                           [ 33%]
test_main.py::test2 FAILED                                               [ 66%]
test_main.py::test3 PASSED                                               [100%]

# convert to windows/dos line endings:

$ unix2dos pytest.out

# load variable:

$ test_summary=$(cat pytest.out)

# verify '\r\n' lines endings loaded into variable:

$ od -c <<< "$test_summary"
... snip ...  3   3   %   ]  \r \n  t   e   s   t ... snip ...

# eumlate OP's echo/output:

$ echo $test_summary
 test_main.py::test3 PASSED [100%]3%]     <== '\r' causes lines to overwrite the same one line
```

Wrapping `$test_summary` in double quotes helps:

```
$ echo "$test_summary"
test_main.py::test_main PASSED                                           [ 33%]
test_main.py::test2 FAILED                                               [ 66%]
test_main.py::test3 PASSED                                               [100%]
```

Alternatively we can strip the `\r` line endings from the variable, eg:

```
$ test_summary="$(test_summary//$'\r'/}"
$ od -c <<< "$test_summary"
... snip ...  3   3   %   ]  \n  t   e   s   t ... snip ...

$ echo $test_summary
test_main.py::test_main PASSED [ 33%] test_main.py::test2 FAILED [ 66%] test_main.py::test3 PASSED [100%]

# still need to wrap in double quotes to properly display all spaces and line endings:

$ echo "$test_summary"
test_main.py::test_main PASSED                                           [ 33%]
test_main.py::test2 FAILED                                               [ 66%]
test_main.py::test3 PASSED                                               [100%]
```

---

A couple other ideas for stripping out the `\r` characters before saving the output in the variable:

```
$ test_summary=$(pytest -v | grep -E ".+\.py::.+[A-Z]+" | tr -d '\r')
$ test_summary=$(pytest -v | grep -E ".+\.py::.+[A-Z]+" | sed 's/\r//g')
$ test_summary=$(pytest -v | grep -E ".+\.py::.+[A-Z]+" | dos2unix)
```

The removal of the `\r` characters could also be applied after the `pytest` call and before the `grep` call (eg, `pytest -v | dos2unix | grep -E ...`).

Comment: You need to double-quote the variable even when it doesn't contain carriage returns, or else it'll print as one line.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to pipe the output of` `pytest` through `dos2unix`?

Comment: @user1934428 thanks for the reminder; I've added an example for using `dos2unix`; as to whether it's 'simpler' ... (imo) it's more of a personal preference, and while my personal preference is indeed `dos2unix`, it's not uncommon to find environments where `dos2unix` is not available so having a couple other options up the proverbial sleeve comes in handy;  ymmv ...

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try with mapfile:

```
...
mapfile -t test_summary <(pytest -v | grep -E ".+\.py::.+[A-Z]+") 
...
```

or

```
mapfile -t test_summary <<< $(pytest -v | grep -E ".+\.py::.+[A-Z]+")
```